# In-App-Purchase: New subscription purchase does not trigger paymentqueue updatedTransactions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm building out subscriptions in an iOS application. 
I have an implementation of a `StoreObserver` that conforms to both `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` and `SKProductsRequestDelegate`. My `StoreObserver` implementation is a singleton and is added to the default payment queue as a transaction observer during `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

I'm currently testing the application in the sandbox environment. When testing with a fresh sandbox user, I am prompted to log in, which I do, followed by the expected dialogs. After receiving the `You're all set! Your purchase has been successfully completed` dialog, I expect a callback to `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions`. However, that callback never fires... until I kill the application and start it again.

Does anyone have context on why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the StoreObserver being registered as the `SKaymentQueue` transaction observer in the `AppDelegate`, registering it *again* before adding a product to the queue seemed to fix the issue.